# My site doesn't load. Been working yesterday, today throws exception - form isn't working

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, model-view-controller, spring

I`m using spring + hibernate.
Yesterday all has been working, I even added few users via "register.jsp". Saved project and ran it again today, something crashed:/

I`m using forms like those:

```
<form:form action="add.htm" commandName="user">
                <ul>
                <li>Login:</li>
                <li><form:input path="username" /></li>
                <li><span style="color:red" style="font-size:10px"><c:out value="${usernameError}"/></span></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                <li>Hasło:</li>
                <li><form:password path="password" /></li>
                <li><span style="color:red" style="font-size:10px"><c:out value="${passwordError}"/></span></li>
                </ul>
</form:form>
```

on my site and after running my Eclipse today I have an exception:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [jsp] in context with path [/Muzycy]
>   threw exception [The absolute uri:
>   http://www.springframework.org/tags/form
>   cannot be resolved in either web.xml
>   or the jar files deployed with this
>   application] with root cause
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The
>   absolute uri:
>   http://www.springframework.org/tags/form
>   cannot be resolved in either web.xml
>   or the jar files deployed with this
>   application

Moreover, mapping .jsp to .htm stopped to work to.

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using maven? If so, try a full clean and build.

```
mvn clean install
```

If that doesn´t work, try to clean the jsp, removing all references to taglibs and just place a simple html to test if the view resolver is working. Then add the tags one by one, maybe you have one missing dependency if using maven, or a missing taglib in your deployment directory.

Comment: I`m not using maven. Also tried to clean project, didn`t help. After deleting only one tag, which is mentioned in exception site loaded, but of course, without filling forms.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an entry of this kind in your web.xml?

```
<jsp-config>
<taglib>
<taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/tags/form</taglib-uri>
<taglib-location>spring-form.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

this effectively gives an alias for a tld file as the url that is being complained about.

If this is the case then tld is now missing. Why it should have been present yesterday and missing today I can't speculate, but check out your build procedures. Look to see whether there's something that should be getting that file from the Spring release you're using.

Comment: No, I have not. I have done a project before without that entry and it still works well. I have problems with the new one.

Comment: after adding your entry nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

it definitely has something to do with one of these possibilities:

1. missing jar file in WEB-INF/lib
2. conflicting library version of jar file in WEB-INF/lib and tomcat's lib folder, e.g: you have spring-1.1.jar in WEB-INF/lib, but you also have spring-1.0.jar in common/lib

Comment: well, where can I find that common/lib folder?
I also have other problem - when clickim right mouse button I do not have "build path" option. Is it possible to activate that option via right mouse button in Eclipse Helios?

Comment: I think he is referring to apache-tomcat-6.0.32/lib as common/lib

Comment: May I recommend one thing, that is to use Eclipse and Tomcat separately. Eventually you will have to know how to configure Tomcat without the help of Eclipse's tool. So, why don't do it earlier? From the most basic, understand build path and class path, it will be good a start. Deployment to tomcat should be as simple as copying war archive to any Tomcat's deploy folder.